# SQLite Unix Epoch week number

Tags: java, sqlite, unix, epoch

I have a small SQLite database in a Java program. I need to group some items by week number in a given year. The table has a date, date time and amount fields as below.

```
timeWeek   time                  dateWeek   date            amount
02         2018-01-14 03:48:54   -9         1514786400000   3400
02         2018-01-14 04:08:13   -9         1514786400000   -830
02         2018-01-14 04:08:40   -9         1514786400000   -71
02         2018-01-14 04:09:06   -9         1514786400000   -46
```

I use the following SQL to get the results.  This is my testing against my time stamp added automatically with each insert.

```
SELECT strftime('%W', time) as timeWeek, time, 
strftime('%W', date) as dateWeek, date, amount
from ledger
```

No matter what I try, I always get -9 in the dateWeek field when it should be 2. My alternative solution is to store the week and year as separate integer fields in the database if I cannot correct my error.

Comment: Define week number.

Comment: Read the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html); you are treating the number as a Julian day number. But these values are not valid Unix timestamps, either.

Comment: Apologies.  The time field is set up as datetime in Sqlite and set to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.  I have read and reread the documentation here:  [link] (https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html). Obviously I don't understand/appreciate it.  The dateweek is suppose to be the week of the current year - so 2018-01-14 is the second week of 2018.

Comment: As I said, define week number. Is week # 1 the first week made of only days from the new year? Is week # 1 hold January 1? Is week # 1 the one with the first occurrence of a certain day-of-week in the new year? Is week # 1 the one with the first Thursday of the new year, per ISO 8601 standard? Or something else? I do not know what SQLite’s definition is, as that goes undocumented beyond `%W week of year: 00-53`. If you provide *your* definition, we may be able to assist you.